# jQuery previous button show

Tags: jquery, button, carousel

I'm very new with jQuery and I use this jQuery carousel. I don't want to use any plugin. But I want to ask how can I show previous button in the beginning of carousel and it must be also red in the beginning/first slide

here is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/94/

```
   $(function(){
var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
var clickCount = 0;
var canClick = true;

itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

//Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

//Place the child elements to their original locations.
refreshChildPosition();

//Set the event handlers for buttons.
$('.btnNext').click(function(e){      
    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(6)").text()!='14' ) {
        $('.btnPrevious').show();
      $(".btnPrevious").css('color', '');
        if(canClick) {
            canClick = false;
            clickCount++;
            //Animate the slider to left as item width 
            carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                left : '-='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
                canClick = true;
            });
            if ($(".carousel").find("li:eq(7)").text()=='14'){
              $(".btnNext").css('color', 'red');
            }
        }
    } 
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){

    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()!=1) {
        $(".btnNext").css('color', '');
        if(canClick){
            canClick = false;
            clickCount--;
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
            lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

            lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
            //Animate the slider to right as item width 
            carousel.finish(true).animate({
                left: '+='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                canClick = true;
            });
            if ($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()=='1'){
              $(".btnPrevious").css('color', 'red');
            }
        }
    } 
});

function refreshChildPosition(){
    carouselChild.each(function(){
        $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
    });
}
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `$(".btnPrevious").css('color', 'red').show();` line in `$(function(){...})`

```
$(function(){
    var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
    var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
    var clickCount = 0;
    var canClick = true;
    $(".btnPrevious").css('color', 'red').show();
    itemWidth =......
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/95/)**

Comment: Removing `display:none` from the CSS is probably better for showing it

Comment: @Rhumborl, Yeah good option, but then OP need to add `.css('color', 'red')` also because need to show button in Red if no previous element exist. So why to change both css and script, just change one.